# Dynamic Connection String Change

Tags: c#, string, dynamic, connection, runtime

I have various servers eg : server 1 , server 2 and so on.... Now when we select a particular server from dropdown the connection string should change. So what i did is added connection string with different name in web.config

Now, on Data Access layer i change the connection string based on the value select from dropdown from UI.
Like dropdown selects server2. The value server 2 is in session and when it comes to Data access layer it switches between the connection string

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Server"] != null)
                {
                    switch (HttpContext.Current.Session["Server"].ToString())
                    {
                        case "AU":
                            _connectionString = GetConnectionStringAU();
                            break;
                        case "US":
                            _connectionString = GetConnectionStringUS();
                            break;
                        default:
                            _connectionString = GetConnectionStringAU();
                            break;
                    }
                }
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
```

But the problem is the data brought on the UI is still of the first server which it connects, so even when the connection string is modified its not connecting to new server. Now am really confused is any connection is made to the dynamic connection server. Please let me know what am i missing.

Comment: What are the possible values of `Session["Server"]`? Are you sure this is not a casing issue, e.g. `Session["Server"]` contains `"us"`?

Comment: Values may be US or AU. So based on value passed it will look into the webconfig and get the required connection string.I have even hardcoded the connection strings but in vain. And yes this is test where session was a easy escape to test. Later will remove those but i have debugged and session values and connection strings are getting fresh values but no data.